# How to make fallback for images correctly?

Tags: nginx

I have the following location that handles my assets:

```
location ~ \.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png) {
  root /var/static;
}
```

So if a request is

```
www.example.com/img/file.png
```

the file.png will be taken from

```
/var/static/css/file.png
```

That's correct. But in some cases I need to handle the following request:

```
 www.example.com/css/file1.png
```

And take it from the img directory

```
 /var/static/img/file1.png
```

How should I change my location?

Comment: I'm confused. Why aren't you using the css dir for `.css` and img for the `.png` in the first place?

Comment: May you provide an example? And what if I'll have the following route www.mysite.com/img/folder/file.png ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don’t use the `root` directive to do this. The `alias` is the correct directive. The `root` is only meant for complete server blocks.

You can use `try_files` if nginx should check the other directory in case the file doesn’t reside in the first directory. If this isn’t the case, you’ll have to find a repeating pattern to which you can apply the regular expression.

Well and at this point a problem arises. If we want to use `try_files` we can’t use `alias` because of [a long standing bug](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). For your specific use case we’ll fall back to using the `root` directive because we can’t achieve it otherwise.

And last but not least, [Melvyn](https://serverfault.com/users/140044/melvyn) is right. You should correct your file system. Use the regular expressions for old links and redirect them with a 301 to the new location.

### Example based on your question

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www;

    location / {

        location ~* ^/[^/]*/(.*)\.(css|js|jpe?g|png)$ {
            root /var/static;
            try_files $uri /img/$1.$2 =404;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: But I may have more that 2 subdirs or none of them. Is it possible to construct uniserval regexp? And where is your alias directive?

Comment: I extended my answer and please read my complete answer regarding `alias`. It’s all there.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't correct at all.

```
location ~ \.(?css|js|jpe?g|png) {
  root /var/static;
}
```

and a request www.example.com/img/file.png will be taken from `/var/static/img/file.png`.

The question mark after the `(` doesn't belong there either. Something else is wrong in your site if a request for `/img/file.png` is taken from the `/var/static/css`. Finally, you should really move the images into the correct directory, rather then using regexes to fix deviations from naming conventions. Or just make a dir `/var/static/media` and be done with it.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: This answer is not very supportive and doesn't seem to try to answer the OP's question at all.